# How do I get Windows 11 to ask which app to use to open a file type or a link type every time, once a default is set? (Or how to reset a default app?)

Tags: windows-11, file-association, default-settings

When opening a specific file (or clicking on a link in a program) Windows will use the default app, set under **Setting > Apps > Default apps**.

I would like to remove the default such that Windows will *ask every time*.

Once you set any individual default, there seems to be no way to undo *only that* default. From what I can tell, the sole option is the nuclear option: *reset all default apps*.

This option isn't the best either. For one, all things browser will revert to Edge. So I can't have *HTTP* links or *html* files ask me every time now. Aside from the browser, zip, image, and txt files have this issue too.

Is there a regkey I can modify to do this?

FWIW: I know I can *right click > open with > XYZ* in Explorer.  But that doesn't solve the issue of opening things from inside other applications that adhere to these settings.

Comment: Not exactly what you request, but there's a tutorial on displaying and importing a list of default apps as XML at https://www.elevenforum.com/t/export-and-import-custom-default-app-associations-for-new-users-in-windows-11.5305/ . This list could be edited to set other defaults -- but I believe simply *removing* one would set the default to that MS chose originally.

Comment: so are you suggesting that if for example i had a default of notepad for txt files, but right clicked and opened one with Notepad++, that if I went to file > Open to open another txt file, that it would launch notepad instead of just opening another tab in notepad++? is that the kind of application issue you are experiencing?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  While that guide does allow me to save and apply settings to other machines, it seems that the third option to wipe defaults doesn't work properly.  I tried it a few times with different types on my systems, the selected defaults remain in settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Q2 2023 the Registry is the way to reset any *individual* default application selection.

## TL;DR

You will need to *Delete* the registry folder `UserChoice` in one of the two following locations and then *Restart* Explorer:

### Path for Link Types (URIs)

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\abcdefg\UserChoice` folder where `abcdefg` is a URI (e.g.: *mailto* or *https*).

### Path for File Types  (File Extensions)

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.XYZ\UserChoice` folder where `XYZ` is a file extension (e.g.: *.zip, .png, or .txt*).

## Steps to "Reset" Defaults

1. *Open* up the Registry Editor
2. *Navigate* to the relative above path.
3. *Delete* the relative `UserChoice` folder.
4. *Close* the Registry Editor
5. *Kill & Restart* Explorer (in Task Manager) or *Reboot* the computer (not always necessary).

---

## Windows' Nomenclatures

URIs: are referred to as "link type" in GUI Settings and "UrlAssociations" in the Registry.

File Extensions: are called "file type" in GUI Settings and "FileExts" in the Registry.

---

## IMHO

In a future update, under *Apps>Defuault Apps*, an option should be added to *Reset* or *Ask Every Time* for an individual selection, since a *Reset all default apps* exists as on option. Any non-power user would have to wipe all their settings just to reset a single one.